# Passing arguments from a variable with white space

Tags: bash, arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, whitespace

I'd like to use a number of arguments defined in a variable when executing a command. Let me illustrate the case with a simple example:

Say I want to copy a file from one destination to another and that I will supply the arguments for cp through a variable. It works fine when the arguments does not contain any spaces:

```
#!/bin/sh
ARGS="file1 file2"

cp $ARGS
```

strace shows the following expected interpretation:

```
execve("/bin/cp", ["cp", "file1", "file2"]
```

However when I use arguments with spaces I cannot get it to work. I've tried putting each argument in escaped quotes and many other things, but it is interpreted as individual arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh
ARGS="\"file1\" \"file2\""

cp $ARGS
```

the result is not two arguments, but four:

```
execve("/bin/cp", ["cp", "\"file", "1\"", "\"file", "2\""]
```

To complicate things even further my final goal is to use variable substitutions within the supplied ARGS variable, but how do I get it to work? Consider the following:

```
FILENAME1="Picture 1.jpg"
FILENAME2="Picture 2.jpg"

ARGS="$FILENAME1 $FILENAME1"

cp $ARGS
```

It results in four arguments:

```
execve("/bin/cp", ["cp", "Picture", "1.jpg", "Picture", "1.jpg"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reliably use a single parameter to store a list of values; there is no way to distinguish between whitespace that is *part* of a value, and whitespace that *separates* values. Use an array instead.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename1="Picture 1.jpg"
filename2="Picture 2.jpg"

args=( "$filename1" "$filename2" )

cp "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that this reveals another difficulty. I need to use pass this across multiple scripts. The single parameter containing my argument list is built in one script and passed to the script that will execute a command that takes these arguments.

How do I pass an array instead of a single parameter?

Comment: You cannot; `"${args[@]}"`  simply expands to a sequence of individual words, each one constituting a separate argument. You may need to redesign the interface between the two scripts.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the clarification. I'll create another question regarding this issue then :)